# Asterisk debug dialplan with incoming number and callerid

Tags: linux, asterisk, pbx, extension, debug

How to debug dialplan with incoming CallerID ?

im haveing context [pstn] with incoming _1000 number and 
CallerID = 123123123 ("external number of calling person")

How can i locally check this situation? 
solution like `dialplan show 123123123@pstn` didnt work cos of pstn allready has 1000 number.
i need something like `dialplan show 1000($CallerID=123123123)@pstn` is there any solution?

Comment: Ive managed to test with another `extension [test]` and setting CallerId variable.
Be careful with `$CallerID check $CallerID(num) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive managed to test with another extension [test] and setting CallerId variable. Be careful with $CallerID check $CallerID(num)